# OS X Chrome Saved Passwords Deleted

Tags: macos, google-chrome, passwords

After running Onyx and a couple other optimization applications (yeah, my fault, I know), it appears Chrome no longer has any saved passwords listed.  However, when I pull up Keychain, all of my passwords and information are there.  I also have a full Time Machine backup of my computer. Is there any way to restore the saved passwords from preferably Keychain and if not that, Time Machine?

Comment: Just restore your full backup?

Comment: I'm not going to restore my entire system for one application. If I could find out what files are modified or where the saved passwords are stored supplementary for Chrome, I would just restore those.

Comment: A great way to find out what files Chrome uses to save passwords is to use the `sudo opensnoop` command from the Terminal. It lists all files as they are accessed. Start the command, switch to Chrome, save a (new) password somewhere, go back to the Terminal, hunt through the output. Alternatively, try filtering the (overwhelming) output, `sudo opensnoop | grep -ei (chrome|google)`.

Comment: Although I've seen Chrome access my Keychain, it doesn't seem to read (or write) any passwords there.  It seems (for me) to check if I've ever said to NOT save a password, but if that isn't true, Chrome will ask me if I want to save it.  And it seems to save it "in Chrome" somewhere, and sync to my other Chromes.  Doesn't seem to save it in Keychain, unless it is actually saving it Keychain *and* Chrome Sync?  Anyway, if you have another Chrome, see if you can push the passwords from that device back out, and get this Mac to pick up the "new" passwords from Chrome Sync.